# Accessing a windows share with groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui, smb

Hey i'm trying to access a windows share to get a given XML file that I need to do some work on. 
I'm trying to do this with a groovy script that will run in soapui, but i can't see how I can access the share without adding something like JCIFS or another external lib.
Is there anyway to access the share without external libs and if not could somebody point me to an example of how you access the share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have tried with the jcifs and that works, but would not be the best.

But we can access with just a normal windows share access.

So if i use: " `\\\\<ip>\\c\$\\folder`" i can get to my files.

Comment: What does "\\c\$" stand for?

Comment: there is \ before the $ sign to escape it